# How to select all from datatable under some condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, filtering

I want to `Select *` from my datatable under some condition and put the return value in the same datatable.

```
 dt = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty( myRow.Field<string>("name") )
      select ;
```

I try something like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i can see from your code is that you like to remove all rows where the field "Name" is empty. Is that correct?

The result you get back is not directly your new datatable. Instead you'll get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` containing all the rows you'd like to see.

Instead you could reverse the outcome of your linq query containing everything you don't like and afterwards simply delete all this stuff from your datatable.

```
var rowsToDelete = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(row => String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("name"))
                     .ToList();

foreach(var row in rowsToDelete)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: when i execute `dt.Rows.Clear();`

`This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.` in the `rowsToDelete`

Comment: @just_name: Yes, i didn't test it (shame on me) and thought a simple copy (with `.ToList()`) would work on the datatable like on every simple list. But that's not true. So i simply removed this approach from my answer and recommend to only use the latter approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new object with non-null values:

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => !row.IsNull("name")).Select(row => { dt2.Rows.Add(row); return true; });
```

Remove null values from existing object:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.IsNull("name")).Select((row, index) => { dt.Rows.RemoveAt(index); return true; });
```

Make changes to existing object:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.IsNull("name")).Select((row, index) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Name in Row # " + index + " is null.");
    row["Status"] = "Disabled";
    return true;
});
```